# Issue launching messaging application of phone in my application

Tags: tizen

I'm developing an application in which i need to launch default messaging application of tizen mobile , I tried using both implicit and explicit launch , it's not able to fetch the application. Problem arises in MIME type. What MIME type or URI should i use to get message app ? please suggest .

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the https://developer.tizen.org/help/topic/org.tizen.native.appprogramming/html/guide/app/appcontrol_message.htm?resultof=%22%61%70%70%63%6f%6e%74%72%6f%6c%22%20

Hope it helps you. :-)

Comment: Thanks :) but i do web app programming , not native . I got the solution :)